# Can you restrict users from using certain connectors in azure logic apps?

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-logic-apps, azure-security, azure-rbac

I've looked through all the permissions a user can have in regards to logic apps but I still have not be able to answer my question. Is it possible to restrict a user from using a certain connector in azure logic apps? For example, lets say I wanted users to use only the Outlook/Office 365 connector. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean ? your users can create logic app but can only use outlook/office 365 connectors ?

Comment: I'm trying to limit access to certain connectors.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to restrict Connectors or Actions at *design time*, though you can certainly restrict actual endpoints by simply not providing credentials.

Note, this is not really any limitation of LogicApps or such.  Limiting the designer experience is not something readily available on any other platform.